# Jenkins. How to get Trigger builds remotely data from POST BODY

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins. How to get Trigger builds remotely data from POST BODY

Quay.io (private docker containers registry) has notification about build status through Webhook POST, data is in body. I tried to google and read Jenkins docs, but found only how to read parameters from URL.

I found a plugin (Generic Webhook Trigger), which is capable to do it partially. It is able to work only with one link (http://{JENKINS_URL}/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke). And to start different jobs i need to use regexp.

At the same time i need to set up minimum 3 notifications on quay.io and a lot of webhooks from different services. Maybe somebody knows how to set up in Jenkins such stuff:

1. Create route like {JENKINS_URL}/jobName/ …
2. Take whole parameters and write it down into $POST_DATA variable.
3. Execute script with $POST_DATA parameter.
   Another manipulations i’m able to do myself in script.

Comment: you want to post how you solved it?

Answer (score -2):

If you have a job like *some-job-name*.

## Question 1:

1. Check the "Trigger builds remotely". Specify a token, like *some-job-name*.
2. Point the webhook to http://{JENKINS_URL}/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=some-job-name .

Now this will be the only job triggered from this request.

## Question 2:

Set the json-path to just *$* and it will evaluate to the entire post data. Use any variable like *variable*.

## Question 3:

Just use the variable from *2* like *$variable*.